# How can "while" be used in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I read a sentence in which "while" was used in different stile.

> Selective herbicides kill specific targets, **while leaving** the desired crop relatively unharmed.

Why don't we have a complete sentence (a verb) after "while"?

> Selective herbicides kill specific targets, **while they are leaving** the desired crop relatively unharmed.
>   Why is it incorrect?

When we use "Gerund" after "while?

and last question: Is this correct too?

> Selective herbicides kill specific targets, **by leaving** the desired crop relatively unharmed.

Comment: 'they're are leaving' as you wish to understand it that way is implicit in the 1st sentence.

Comment: Note that "stile" and "style" are completely different things.

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se] Suggesting migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/while) lists this syntactic usage as a subordinator:

> **while**
>
> conj
>
> 1. (subordinating) at the same time that: please light the fire while I'm cooking.
> 2. (subordinating) all the time that: I stay inside while it's raining.
> 3. (subordinating) in spite of the fact that: while I agree about his brilliance I still think he's rude.
> 4. (coordinating) whereas; and in contrast: flats are expensive, while houses are cheap.
>
> **5. (subordinating; used with a gerund [better, *ing*-form]) during the activity of: while walking I often whistle.** [/ I often whistle while walking.]

Obviously this involves a deletion of *I am* after while.

However, the pragmatic force of contrast present in sense 4 above is also involved here:

*Selective herbicides kill specific targets, while they leave the desired crop relatively unharmed.* = *Selective herbicides kill specific targets, but they leave the desired crop relatively unharmed.*

Collins misses this usage (but at the same time [used with *ing*-form]).

Answer (score 2):

Your first and 2nd sentences **do not mean** the same.

*Selective herbicides kill specific targets, **while leaving the desired crop relatively unharmed**.*

The bolded means:

***while leaving the desired crop relatively unharmed*** = and **the manner** in which they do the killing leaves the desired crop relatively unharmed

This

*Selective herbicides **kill** specific targets, **by leaving** the desired crop relatively unharmed.*

is wrong, because

*"**kill ... by leaving** the desired crop relatively unharmed"*

means that the mechanism of killing **consists of** "leaving the desired crop relatively unharmed," which is false.

Your 1st sentence is correct in that respect.

For one thing,

***Selective herbicides*** kill specific **targets**, while **they** are leaving the desired crop relatively unharmed.

is incorrect because "they" has an **ambiguous pronoun reference**: it can be seen as referring "Selective herbicides" or "targets," the latter by proximity.

For another, the bolded in:

*Selective herbicides kill specific targets, **while they are leaving the desired crop relatively unharmed.***

means:

***while they are leaving the desired crop relatively unharmed*** = and **at the same time** they are leaving the desired crop relatively unharmed.

Thus the 2nd parts of 1 and 2 do not mean quite the same.